# Ruby-on-rails: jQuery-ui and asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, asset-pipeline

I'm looking for a little clarity to my better understanding on Rails' asset pipeline.
What I'd like to do is I want to use jQuery-ui components with rails having asset pipeline enabled.

Asset pipeline is quite something new to me. 
Basically, I know what asset pipeline does in general and how it looks through assets in the search tree.
But from the picture below, I got no idea how and where to place stylesheets folder shipped 
with the jQuery-ui download to get it working in my project or to set it up rightly. So, the designated theme can apply to the UI I'm rendering with jQuery-ui as desired.

[image]

Is the application.css file the very place I should put in a reference to that theme?

My best guess is it might be working if I add the theme folder at the second line in application.css below:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree ., ./ui-lightness
```

but what I got was 
Error compiling CSS asset

ArgumentError: wrong mumber of arguments (2 for 1)

Please shed some light on me how to get this working as I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `*= require_tree ., ./ui-lightness` to

```
*= require_tree .
*= require ui-lightness/name_of_css_file
```

Also you need to copy the images included in the downloaded bundle to `app/assets/images/ui-lightness` directory. (Needless to say that create new folder)

Open the css files from downloaded images, find and replace `url: ("../images/image_name.jpg` to `url: ("image_name.jpg")`

This will set the appropriate image paths. Its advisable to put 3rd party library into `vendor/assets` dir. But no harm in putting it into regular assets dir until you can identify which css/js files belong to 3rd party

Answer (score 0):

You can't put several things inside a `require_tree` line. Just split this line

```
*= require_tree ., ./ui-lightness
```

into two lines:

```
*= require_tree .
*= require_tree ./ui-lightness
```